# String Format with numbers or Space

Tags: c#, .net, string, format

I am working on Simple Mask DatePicker, In that the `Text` is Formatted as like a Mask..

For that, am using the String formats.. My question is how to format the below code,

```
string.Format("{0:00-00-0000}", 2)
```

**Output:** `"20-00-0000"`

What i required is,

**Expected**: `"2 -  -    "`

And for this,

```
string.Format("{0:00-00-0000}", 2203)
```

**Expected**: `"22-03-    "`

How could i format like this?

Comment: How would you expect to use this? i.e. how would you pass in a date string value for formatting?

Comment: so you are always expecting a date value, so y don't you create a method which accept the date and return the expected format

Comment: @Sankarann see my answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402409/how-to-replace-deleted-character-with-0-in-the-textbox/21402747#21402747) - I think you are trying to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I understand what you need (I think). Try this instead:

```
string.Format("{0}        ", 2).Substring(0, 8).Insert(2, "-").Insert(5, "-");
```

So format as number, ensure padded with relevant number of spaces, and then insert the `-` characters.

Comment: I think you will need to use a string rather than integer here as the input though - as there is no way to understand if leading zeros were intended - eg 02 wont work